# Скрыть выпавшийся список меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

HTML

```
       <div class="box">
            <p>Dropdown Menu 1</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Menu 1</li>
                <li>Menu 2</li>
                <li>Menu 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <p>Dropdown Menu 2</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Menu 1</li>
                <li>Menu 2</li>
                <li>Menu 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <p>Dropdown Menu 3</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Menu 1</li>
                <li>Menu 2</li>
                <li>Menu 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
           .box {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
                width: 150px;
                position: relative;
            }

            .box p {
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 20px;
            }

            .box ul {
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100%;
                left: -999999px;
                opacity: 0;                 
            }

            .box.active ul {
                opacity: 1;
                left: 0;
            }
```

JS

```
$(".box p").click( function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $(".box").removeClass("active");

    $(this).closest(".box").addClass("active");

});
```

Проблема в моем коде в том, что если я кликну на уже выпавший список то он не закрывается. То есть мне нужно чтобы при клике на выпавший список закрылся прежний открывшийся. Или если я кликну на открывшийся то он тоже должен закрыться. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, это должно решить вашу проблему

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

а я бы сделал вот так

```
$(".box").click( function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

$(this).toggleClass("active");

});
```

Comment: Да это можно. Но вы не скрыли оставшиеся выпавшие меню.

Comment: тогда вот так https://jsfiddle.net/KLON/d32hqm5n/1/
добавляем обертку в меню и немного jquery магии ^_-